# How do I unjoin text?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm messing around with 2.79b and I combined some text for this animation or whatever, and now I have to unjoin them for a few frames. I've tried everything I can think of but nothing is letting me unjoin them. Pressing P isn't working, unlinking them isn't working. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Select the text In edit mode, press P and click separate by loose parts.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing **P** should work for this sort of task. If it is something you want to animate by joining and separating, isn't it best to use shape keys instead.

Comment: You'd think using P would work but it doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: Do you really have to combine them that way. I assume the combining is so that it can act as one object but parenting would work just fine. You can even use a less destructive method using "child of" in object constraints tab. It has an influence which you can adjust. Tbh, this is the way I would go about it.

Comment: Could've swore I've done that. Guess not. Looks like everythings working.

Comment: I'm glad it's working fine now.